# how to collect flow from one place and cancel from another?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a flow:

```
fun startCountingTimer(coroutineContext: CoroutineContext, leftSeconds: Int): Flow<Int> {
return flow {
    for (i in leftSeconds downTo 0) {
        delay(1000)
        emit(i)
    }
 }
}
```

I want to collect it from one place :

```
startWaitingTimer().collect {
    ...
}
```

and cancel from another:

```
startWaitingTimer().cancel()
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`launchIn`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/launch-in.html) to return a [`Job`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/index.html). When you're done, [`cancel`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/cancel.html) the job.

```kotlin
val job = startWaitingTimer(10).onEach { ... }.launchIn(scope)

// Later...
job.cancel()
```